# Proof that the interior of any set is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

If S $\subseteq \Bbb R$ and $x \in \text{int}(S)$, then $\exists r>0$ such that the open ball $B_r(x) \subseteq S$. It is known that the open balls are open sets in $\Bbb R$ then $B_r(x)$ is open. If $y \in B_r(x)$, then there is some $r_0>0: B_{r_0} \subseteq B_r(x)$, so $y \in \text{int}(S)$ because 
$$\text{int}(S) := \{z\in S\mid\exists \varepsilon > 0: B_{\varepsilon}(z) \subseteq S\} $$ 
which is equivalent to 
$$\text{int}(S) = \bigcup_{x\in \text{int}(S)} B_{\varepsilon_x}(x)$$ 
then $B_{r_0}(y) \subseteq \text{int}(S)$, therefore $\text{int}(S)$ open and because  $S$ is arbitrary, the interior of $any$ set is open.

I'm not 100% sure if the proof is right, particularly the part that i say that the interior of $S$ is the union of the open balls of its elements.

Comment: To me, the interior is by defintion the union of all open sets contained in $S$...

Comment: @JuliusL33t It depends on your text. Clearly the OPs text defines interior as the set of all of interior points.  If we used your definition the question would still remain how to prove that all the interior points of S form an open set.

Comment: You are 90% there.  You just need to state that *all* $y\in B_r(x) \in int S$ so $B_r(x) \subset int S$ (that's what subset means) so $x$ is an interior point of $int S$.  So $int S$ is open.

Comment: "wich is equivalent to say that
intS=∪x∈intSBεx(x)"  I don't see that and I don't see how that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any $x \in Int \ S$. I will show you that there exists a ball $N_x$ around $x$ completely contained in $Int \ S $.

By assumption, there exists a ball $N_x$ with $N_x \subseteq S $. So take any point $y \in N_x$. As you note, balls are open, so there exists a ball $N_y \subseteq N_x \subseteq S$ around $y$. But this means by definition that $y \in Int \ S$. Thus, if $y\in N_x$, then $y\in Int \ S$, and so $N_x \subseteq Int \ S $, and $Int \ S$ is open.